# How to run a CURL command n number times I

Tags: api, curl, splunk

I have the following curl command which should run 900 times and then do a curl to push data to splunk.

CURL:
SITEINFO=`curl -H "Authorization: Token <Token>" -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4" "https://netbox.n.com/api/dcim/devices/?limit=1&offest=0&site=a5s"`

After running the command for 900 times (there are 900 devices) .I want to push the data to splunk using another curl.

curl -k http://localhost:8088/services/collector/event -H 'Authorization: Splunk ' -d '{"sourcetype": "Netbox","event": '"$SITEINFO"'}'

Comment: what shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Via looping

```
i=0
while ["$i" -lt 90]
   curl -H "Authorization: Token <Token>" -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4" "https://netbox.n.com/api/dcim/devices/?limit=1&offest=0&site=a5s"
   i = `expr $a + 1`
done
```

store this file as `curl_runner.sh`
And then set permission to `chmod a+x curl_runner.sh`
And run `./curl_runner.sh`